# How to compare hexadecimal numbers with hexadecimal numbers in shell?

Tags: bash, shell

How to compare hexadecimal number with hexadecimal numbers in shell?

Comment: What do you mean?  Do you want "0xdead" to be equal to "dEad" or "57005"?  More detail is needed.

Comment: and include what you have tried so far. Good luck.

Comment: actually am writing like this.... if test $1 -eq "00"
where $1 is a hexadecimal value.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

At least `bash` supports hexadecimal integers directly, provided that they are prefixed with `0x`:

```
$ [[ 0xdead -lt 0xcafe ]] && echo yes || echo no
no
$ [[ 0xdead -gt 0xcafe ]] && echo yes || echo no
yes
```

You just use the comparison operators normally...

Comment: hey i have one more doubt :how to check whether input is number or string ?

Comment: @bd1257 6 years late, but try `case "$num" in ''|*[!a-fA-F0-9]*) echo "not hex";; *) echo "hex";; esac` to test for hexadecimal numbers.

Answer (score 3):

You can convert your hex numbers into decimals using `printf` and then you can compare the numeric values, e.g.:

```
x="0xdead"
y="0xcafe"

x_num=$(printf "%d" "$x")
y_num=$(printf "%d" "$y")

if [ $x_num -gt $y_num ]; then
    echo "x is my value"
else
   echo "x is not my value"
fi
```

Comment: With bash version >= 3.1 this is possible, too: `printf -v x_num "%d" "$x"`

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
(( "$answer" == 0x42 ))
echo $?

answer=0xDEADCAFE
(( "$answer" == 0xDEADCAFE ))
echo $?
```