# Compare Hex Numbers in Shell

Tags: linux, bash, comparison, hex

I want to compare the first element of every line in A.txt with the the first element of B.txt lines and if they match print that line of A.
Both first line elements of A and B are hexadecimal numbers and I have written the following code based on https://askubuntu.com/questions/366879/awk-comparing-the-value-of-two-variables-in-two-different-files.

```
#!/bin/bash
A="$HOME/A.txt"
B="$HOME/B.txt"

cat $A | while read a; do
a1=$(echo $a | awk ' { print $1 }')
    cat $B | while read b; do
        b1=$(echo $b | awk ' { print $1 }')
        if [ $a1 == $b1 ]; then
            echo $a
        fi
    done
done
```

Here is what I get: 
line 9: [0x6200e001: command not found

Comment: This would happen if you didn't have a space between the `[` and the `$a1`. Did you try running the code after you cleaned it up to post it?

Comment: Are you sure there is a space immediately after the square bracket?

Comment: Both of you are right. got solved!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to compare hexadecimal numbers with hexadecimal numbers in shell?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13500866/608639).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem occurs if you don't have a space between the `[` and the `$a1` in your code. Always test the exact code you post -- don't assume your clean version will exhibit the same problem as your actual code.

Here's how to reproduce it:

```
$ cat file
a1=0x6200e001
b1=$a1
[$a1 == $b1 ]

$ bash file
file.sh: line 3: [0x6200e001: command not found

$ shellcheck file

In file line 3:
[$a1 == $b1 ]
 ^-- SC1035: You need spaces after the opening [ and before the closing ].
```

The fix is to add the space:

```
[ $a1 == $b1 ]
```

You should optimally also quote the variables to prevent trouble with whitespace and glob characters:

```
[ "$a1" = "$b1" ]
```

Comment: http://shellcheck.net is a handy website for linting sh/bash scripts; a CLI version - as demonstrated in this answer - can be built from source - see https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck. In bash, it is generally preferable to use the more robust and feature-rich `[[...]]` rather than `[...]`; using `[[...]]` also obviates the need for double-quoting variable references.

Answer (score 2):

Using awk to replace all

```
#!/bin/bash

A="$HOME/A.txt"
B="$HOME/B.txt"

awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1];next} $1 in a' $B $A
```