# Hex compare in bash scripting

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting, fedora

I am facing some issue when I am reading the 3rd word(a hex string) of each line in a text file and compare it with a hex number. Can some one please help me on it.

```
#!/bin/bash
A=$1

cat $A | while read a; do
a1=$(echo \""$a"\" | awk '{ print $3 }')
#echo $a > cut -d " " -f 3
echo $a1
(("$a1" == 0x10F7))
echo $?
done
```

But when I use below, the comparison happens correctly,

```
a1= 0xADCAFE
(( "$a1" == 0x10F7 ))
echo $?
```

Then why it is showing issue when I read like below,

```
a1=$(echo \""$a"\" | awk '{ print $3 }')
or> a1=$(echo $a | awk '{ print $3 }')
```

`echo $a` prints intended hex value, but comparison does not happen.

Regards,

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what's going wrong yet. We can start by simplifying the script though. Try starting with `awk '{ print $3 }' "$A" | while read a1; do` and removing the `a1=…` line. Also add the output of the script to your question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to compare hexadecimal numbers with hexadecimal numbers in shell?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13500866/608639)

Answer (score 2):

Running Awk inside a `while read` loop is an antipattern.  Just do the loop in Awk; it's good at that.

```
awk '$3 == 4343' "$1"
```

If you want to compare against a string whose value is `"0x10F7"` then it's

```
awk '$3 == "0x10F7"' "$1"
```

If you want to match either, case insensitively etc, a regex is a good way to do that.

```
awk '$3 ~ /^(0x10[Ff]7|4343)$/' "$1"
```

Notice how the `$1` in double quotes is handled by the shell, and gets replaced by a (properly quoted!) copy of the script's first command-line argument before Awk runs, while the Awk script in single quotes has its own namespace, so `$3` is an Awk variable which refers to the third field in the current input line.

Either way, avoid the [useless use of `cat`](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html) and **always always always** quote variables which contain file names with double quotes.

That's literal double quotes.  You seem to have tried both a dangerous bare `$a` and a doubly double-quoted `"\"$a\""` where the simple `"$a"` would be what you actually want.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you all for your responses, Now my script is working fine. I was trying to match two files, below script does the purpose

```
#!/bin/bash
A=$1
B=$2

dos2unix -f "$A"
dos2unix -f "$B"
rm search_match.txt search_data_match.txt search_nomatch.txt   search_data_nomatch.txt

while read  line;do
    search_word=$(echo $line | awk '{ print $1 }')

    grep "$search_word" $B >> temp_file.txt

    while read var;do
        file1_hex=$(echo $line | awk '{ print $2 }')
        file2_hex=$(echo $var | awk '{ print $3 }')

        (("$file1_hex" == "$file2_hex"))
        zero=$(echo $?)
        if [ "$zero" -eq 0 ] ; then

            echo $line >> search_match.txt
            echo $var >> search_data_match.txt
        else
            echo $line >> search_nomatch.txt
            echo $var >> search_data_nomatch.txt
        fi
    done < "temp_file.txt"
    rm temp_file.txt
done < "$A"
```

Comment: You still don't quote your file name variables properly.  Your script will fail as soon as `$1` or `$2` contains whitespace or other shell metacharacters.  Also, if you assign `$1` and `$2` to other variables immediately, better make those variables actually mean something -- otherwise you might as well use `"$1"` and `"$2"` throughout your script.

Comment: Also, the `zero=$(echo $?)` is a massive [useless use of `echo`](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#echo) -- you'll simply want `if (("$file1_hex" == "$file2_hex")); then ...`

Comment: The `grep` with a temporary file would be more elegantly expressed as `grep "$search_word" "$2" | while read var` without the temporary file.

Comment: And I'll repeat my observation that this looks like it desperately wants to be an Awk script instead, but I'll leave it at that for now.